# Create msi with Wix Bootstrapper

Tags: wix, windows-installer, bootstrapper

I have a working wix bootstrapper, chaining two wix msi installers, and it works fine.
The output file of the bootstrapper is an exe file, I am interested in changing the output file to be an MSI file, is it possible with bootstrapper?
If so, how do i achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Bootstrappers have to be executables, not MSI packages. If you want to write your own bootstrapper from scratch, you could use EmbeddedChainer to create an .msi with a chainer inside it, on Windows Installer 4.5 and later.